# Debugging an unnecessary newline character in a Kubernetes secret

Tags: kubernetes, base64

I have an environment variable called `GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIONS_API_KEY`, populated by a Kubernetes secret `YAML`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: google-maps-directions-api-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIONS_API_KEY: QUl...QbUpqTHNJ
```

The secret was created by copy-pasting the result of running `echo -n "AIz..." | base64` on my API key. I've provided the beginning and the end of the key in this code snippet, to show that there is no newline in the key included in the secret file.

Here is what I see when I run `cat google-maps-directions-api-key-secret.yaml | hexdump -C`:

```
00000000  61 70 69 56 65 72 73 69  6f 6e 3a 20 76 31 0a 6b  |apiVersion: v1.k|
00000010  69 6e 64 3a 20 53 65 63  72 65 74 0a 6d 65 74 61  |ind: Secret.meta|
00000020  64 61 74 61 3a 0a 20 20  6e 61 6d 65 3a 20 67 6f  |data:.  name: go|
00000030  6f 67 6c 65 2d 6d 61 70  73 2d 64 69 72 65 63 74  |ogle-maps-direct|
00000040  69 6f 6e 73 2d 61 70 69  2d 73 65 63 72 65 74 0a  |ions-api-secret.|
00000050  74 79 70 65 3a 20 4f 70  61 71 75 65 0a 64 61 74  |type: Opaque.dat|
00000060  61 3a 0a 20 20 47 4f 4f  47 4c 45 5f 4d 41 50 53  |a:.  GOOGLE_MAPS|
00000070  5f 44 49 52 45 43 54 49  4f 4e 53 5f 41 50 49 5f  |_DIRECTIONS_API_|
00000080  4b 45 59 3a 20 51 55 6c  36 59 56 4e 35 51 7a 68  |KEY: QUl6YVN5Qzh|
...
000000b0  51 62 55 70 71 54 48 4e  4a                       |QbUpqTHNJ|
000000b9
```

But! When I step into a Node.JS interpreter inside of the pod, I see the following:

```
> process.env.GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIONS_API_KEY
'AIz...jLsI\n'
```

There is an auxiliary newline character appended to the end of the string!

This is, frankly, extremely frustrating. I have several questions on this subject.

- Can you spot my error? E.g. at what point in the secret propagation pipeline am I accidentally inserting that newline?
- What Unix command should I use to print a newline character to console in such a way that it is interpreted literally (as a `\n`), so that I can *actually see it*?
- Is it considered bad practice to inject code removing trailing newlines from environment variables into my container image? I know this is not technically correct, but this hurts like hell.

Comment: do you have the pod spec used to consume this secret/envvar?

Comment: All the definitions are available [here](https://github.com/ResidentMario/subway-explorer-deploy).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you previously created the secret without the `-n` option to `echo`,  verify the Secret persisted in the API (`kubectl get secret/google-maps-directions-api-secret -o yaml`) matches the secret in your yaml file, and also verify the consuming app has been redeployed since the secret was updated with the correct value

Comment: Ah, here's the piece of information I was missing: secrets manage their own lifecycle and must be recreated on update manually. They won't do it themselves when the underlying file changes. Thanks.

Comment: that is true for all resource manifests... `kubectl apply -f <file>` loads the current content of `<file>` into the apiserver. any changes you make in the future have to be updated/reapplied to take effect in the API

Comment: that's so stupid! I was just debugging an issue for hours and I was finally able to narrow down to this problem by running "env". The [k8s secrets doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) didn't include how to "properly" generate a simple base64 string

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything odd with how your secret looks. As you alluded to, the first thing I would do is `exec` into the pod, drop into bash, and echo out the environment variable to confirm it's propagated incorrectly. After doing a quick test, the newline should show up fine with a printf:

```
printf '%s' $GOOGLE_MAPS_DIRECTIONS_API_KEY
```

If it looks fine when printing it from bash, then the issue is with how node is interpreting it. If it looks messed up, then you need to take another look at how you're generating it.

FYI if the result of `process.env` is actually your API key, you should revoke it ASAP as you just published it in your question.

As for whether it's bad practice to strip newlines, yes. This can cause unexpected issues down the line if an actual piece of secret information contains a newline.

Comment: Yes, I will have to do it. I slipped up there, too much redaction while editing the question.

Comment: No worries, pretty sure we've all been there! The old version still shows up in your list of revisions on the on the question itself, just a heads up.

Answer (score 1):

As Jordan Liggitt says, solution is encoding secret values using `echo -n your-value-here | base64` instead of `echo your-value-here | base64`

`echo` by default adds a break line, `-n` option prevents it

Comment: Is this a restatement or thank you to this other answer: [Debugging an unnecessary newline character in a Kubernetes secret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49158137)